# How to add usb wifi adapter support to android build?

Tags: wifi, kernel

I have kernel version : `2.6.38.8 #9`, the output for `lsusb` is  `Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:8179`. Can anyone help to find correct drivers for this chipset and how to add drivers to kernel ?

Comment: Are you running Android?  The last I heard was that USB on the Pi was not really functional with Android.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably a Realtek RTL 8188EE chipset.  You can usually find enough clues about stuff like this simply by searching online for "linux 0bda:8179".  Once it is clear there is an in-tree driver, you can find it in the kernel source tree by poking around in the right place...from the top level:

```
cd drivers/net/wireless/rtlwifi
grep -R 8179 .
```

Turns up:

```
./rtlwifi/rtl8188ee/sw.c:       {RTL_PCI_DEVICE(PCI_VENDOR_ID_REALTEK, 0x8179, rtl88ee_hal_cfg)},
```

So `rtl8188ee` is almost certainly the name of the driver, this can be confirmed by looking in the `Kconfig` file in the above directory.

That's for a recent 3.x kernel, however.  Realtek, being one of the larger wifi manufacturers, seems to spawn new chipsets pretty regularly and have a sort of half on, half off the boat attitude toward providing linux drivers -- they did write the stuff in the rtlwifi directory, but I think they do not keep up with their own product releases this way.  Development on the 2.6 kernel mostly stopped almost 4 years ago, so you may or may not find this there (and the copyright on that driver code is 2009-2013, so it has obviously gone through updates).